# Adding an Image field in webform module

Tags: entities, webforms, media

I am a newbie to drupal 7 and just started working with it a couple of months ago. My problem is I am making a ["webform"](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) where the user filling the form should upload his image. But as there is no such field I am not able to understand how to do it.....

I also tried the "[entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform)"  but as I install it and enable it, the edit links all over my website starts throwing an exception...

So please help me. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't there a file field available when you try to create a new webform? File field should be in the core in drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

**To add an image field to a webform:**

- To go the webform tab where you manage the fields.
- Add a new field of type file: [image: Showing adding file field]
- On the new field configuration page it's a good idea to set an Upload directory for your images. This means all the images upload from this field will sit in a particular folder in your files directly and help prevent too many files from sitting in one folder. You can also choose what types of files you want to allow users to upload. For an image field I would suggest only gif, jpg, and png.
- Set any other settings such a label or display settings as required.
- Finally save the component.
- Now when you visit the frontend of your webform you should see your new field:

[image: image upload field on frontend]

Answer (score -1):

Try [Plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload) for a start. Hope this helps.

Comment: Plupload is for uploading multiple images at the same time and is not required for just uploading an image to a webform. Also integrating plupload and webforms would be a considerable challenge!

Answer (score -1):

In Webform - If you navigate to manage field of it. Then you should will be able to see field type as **Image**. Just add one field with that Image type after that you can upload your image.

If you are not able to see then check your Drupal db log. Might be there is error you will get to fix.

Comment: There is no image field type in webform. For images the file field type is used.

Comment: Yes, we can use default file as field type then we can give image type extensions in settings.

Answer (score -2):

I'd recommend you to try [Webform Select Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_select_image). This module adds a new image component to the webform.

> The purpose of this module is to add an images select component for webform (checkboxes or radios buttons).
>
> 1. Download and enable this module
> 2. Go to webform components admin page
> 3. Choose "Select image"
> 4. Upload your image, choose image style and other component settings

Comment: This functionality requested is available with just the webform module using the file field type. The module you linked to is not for uploading images at all, but instead for adding images to select options.